# How to launch barcodescanner at start ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm creating a simple barcodescanner app with ionic using the barcodescanner plugin.

I can launch the scanner by pressing the button, but I want to launch the scanner when I lauch the app.

I've tried launching the scanner via the constructor of my page:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, private safariViewController: SafariViewController) {
      this.scanObject();
  }
```

And also via the following function:

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){

        this.scanObject();
  }
```

Below the function I'm calling:

```
  scanObject(){

    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
      // Success! Barcode data is here
      //alert(barcodeData.text);
      this.processScanResult(barcodeData.text);
     }, (err) => {
         // An error occurred
     });
  }
```

Comment: so what happens ? any errors in console?

Comment: @SurajRao It opens the HomePage, but not the scanner

Comment: did you try calling from within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`?

Comment: @SurajRao I've changed that, and it is now working. But when the app is in the background, I want the barcodescanner to show again when opening the app.

Comment: You can use `this.onResumeSubscription = platform.resume.subscribe(() => { blah blah });` to achieve this